# jQuery content of parents

Tags: jquery

How can I get from `function (e)` the contents of parents, namely `#message` and `#date`?

JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '#quote', function (e) {
    // How to get here content of #message, #date of that div where Quote was clicked?
    // Example "PostNumber 751883","7/31/2009 12:00:00 AM"
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
      <div class="flexbox-date">
        <div class="topic-header">
          <div class="date-item">
            <div style="display: flex">
              <div style="align-self: center" id="date">
                7/31/2009 12:00:00 AM
              </div>
              <div style="align-self: center">
                <a id="quote" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Quote</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="message" class="flexbox-message">PostNumber 751883</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
      <div class="flexbox-date">
        <div class="topic-header">
          <div class="date-item">
            <div style="display: flex">
              <div style="align-self: center" id="date">
                7/22/2009 12:00:00 AM
              </div>
              <div style="align-self: center">
                <a id="quote" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Quote</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="message" class="flexbox-message">PostNumber 743123</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Id must be unique. You can not have multiple `id="quote"` or `id="message"`

Comment: I agree with @Carsten, just change the id into class and use it as your target. lets do best practices! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get its parent element up to `<li>` tag from there, find the `#message` and `#date` elements

use closest:

```
console.log($(this).closest('li').find("#date").text())
console.log($(this).closest('li').find("#message").text())
```

just trim it.

Comment: put this inside  your click event

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `id` of an html tag only once per page. Addtionally you should put your inline `style`s into css files if possible.

I modified your html with classes and you can try the following jQuery as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.quote').on('click', quoteClick);
  
  function quoteClick(event) {
    var parent = $(event.target).closest('li');
    
    if (parent.length) {
      var date = parent.find('.date').text();
      var message = parent.find('.flexbox-message').text();
      
      console.log(date);
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
      <div class="flexbox-date">
        <div class="topic-header">
          <div class="date-item">
            <div style="display:flex; ">
              <div style="align-self: center;" class="date">
                7/31/2009 12:00:00 AM
              </div>
              <div style="align-self: center;">
                <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm quote">Quote</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-message">
        PostNumber 751883
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
      <div class="flexbox-date">
        <div class="topic-header">
          <div class="date-item">
            <div style="display:flex;">
              <div style="align-self: center;" class="date">
                7/22/2009 12:00:00 AM
              </div>
              <div style="align-self: center;">
                <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm quote">Quote</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-message">
        PostNumber 743123
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```